# Name for a group action which is almost regular

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$. We say that the action of $G$ on $X$ is *regular* if for any two elements $x,y \in X$ there exists exactly one element $g \in G$ such that $gx = y$.

Is there a name for a group action such that for any two elements $x,y \in X$ there exists the same number of elements $g \in G$ such that $gx = y$? In other words I require the size of the following sets to be equal $\{ g \in G: gx = y \}$ for all pairs $x,y \in X$.

Comment: This is equivalent to be a transitive action, you might want to call it a "transitive action".

Comment: The definition of transitive action only mentions the existence of an element $g \in G$ such that $gx = y$, given $x,y \in X$. How does one see the equivalence?

Comment: You have in general that $Stab(g.x)=gStab(x)g^{-1}$ so if $G$ acts transitively on $X$, all $x\in X$ have isomorphic stablizers. Finally :

Comment: if $g_0\in G$ such that $g_0.x=y$ then $\{g\in G\mid g.x=y\}=g_0Stab(x)$ which is in bijection with $Stab(x)$.

Comment: I see. Great, thanks!

Comment: But just transitivity does not capture the condition in the question, surely if the action is transitive, all these sets have the same size. But the question ask what happens if they have a given number of elements, what is implied for example if the size of the stabilizers is bounded by a number. Also even for nontransitive actions, the stabilizers on different orbits could be equal in size.

Comment: @Stefan no. If the action is not transitive, there will be a pair $x,y$ for which $|\{g\inG\mid g.x=y\}|=0$. If this action satisfies the requested condition it is the trivial action (which is not so interesting). So the essential situation is when you have a transitive action.

Comment: @DavidHill: As $1 \in \{g\in G : gx = x\}$ no such action exists. But if we just require that $|\{g\in G : gx = y \}| \le k$, i.e. bounded and not equal, that question might be interesting. I suggest that the questioner changes his question that way. And let me note: If the action is transitive, as each transitive action is equivalent to an action on some subgroup which forms a stabilizer then, and vice versa, the original question reduces to, classify the group with a subgroups of a given order $n$.